# segue and send email swift

Tags: ios, swift, email, segue

I'm new in IOS swift development, I would like to know: When it comes of sending an email, is it possible to take the email's message after it was sent or while it is sending from the mailComposeViewController and segue it to a new view controller.Thank you for you help.

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: UIButton) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if (textField1.text.isEmpty || textField2.text.isEmpty || textField3.text.isEmpty) 
      {
        println("Error")
      } 
    else 
     {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() 
       {
   self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)     
        } 
       else 
        {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }

    }
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["email.test@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Title")
    //the message body is filed with 3 textFields, already declared
    //need to send then to another view after send email
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(textField1.text+textField2.text+textField3.text,
        isHTML: true)

    return mailComposerVC
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "send") {
        var view: UIViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        //the same textFields in email here...
        //blank
    }
}
```

EDIT: This second view got a array, i need fill this array with the fields1, 2 and 3, for the example:

```
if (segue.identifier == "send") {
        var view: UIViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        view.array = [textField1.text, textField2.text, textField3.text]
    }
}
```

and this is the second view i want to segue:

```
class Agenda: UITableViewController {

var array = []

var end = ""
var area = ""
var data = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    end = self.array[0] as! String
    area = self.array[1] as! String
    data = self.array[2] as! String
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AgendaCell

    cell.endereco.text = end
    cell.area.text = area
    cell.data.text = data

    return cell
    }
}
```

the cell got 3 labels, and each one need to be filed in order, that's the question how i make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate the three textfields text into one fullMessage then just prepare some string or data structure to receive it

```
var fullMessage :String {
  return textfield.text + textfield1.text + textfield2.text
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "send "{
     var destination = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
      destination.recievemessage = fullMessage

    }
}
```

Comment: and what i do to send email, then after segue to another view?

Comment: after the button send was pressed put this in the send button **performSegueWithIdentifier("send", sender: sender)**

Comment: i add at storyboard the segue at send button, but for a sec it opens the view the right after back to email form, i make wrong the segue connection?

Comment: your send button should let the email go then dismiss the actual controller then send the data to the second view controller

Comment: please one more question, this fields i want store in recievemessage but in array from the second view, this way is not working, how i can segue in array?

Comment: can you elaborate on that question again ?